# Why are newline escape characters removed when project is live on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, html-escape-characters

I'm sending a string through my server built in Node.js with a few newline escapes in the string. When running on localhost they work as expected, but when the project is pushed live on Heroku the characters are either not getting passed in the string or they are not working as expected.

I'm not sure what to try as I feel I'm using the escape characters correctly. Newlines are present at the bottom of this code snippet.

```
main: {
            testimonials: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    img: '/static/img/testimonials/Headshot - User - company.jpg',
                    firstName: 'Mike',
                    lastName: 'Smith',
                    role: 'Developer at company',
                    messageSnippet: "Yes, IB taught to me to code, but it was so much more than that. This course reshaped my entire life completely and set me on the path to ultimate success. \n \n I have a dream job at company, and I couldn't be happier. I am forever thankful to everyone involved and highly recommend it to anyone looking to start afresh.",
                }
```

Expected: Newline's work in the deployed environment as they do as when I'm testing them on my localhost server.

Actual: Newline's used on localhost work as expected, but on when deployed to Heroku they are not present in the string or have taken any effect on the string they were in.